# hive delete data with insert in partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table partitioned based on date. When I insert data into it, the partitions are not overwritten.

Note: I am inserting multiple partitions using a dynamic partition.

Below is the query:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
insert overwrite table test1 partition(ds)
select user_id,ds
    from temp
    where ds between '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-01';
```

Comment: Is there any error message? Can you share the logs? Can you check the partition update timestamp?

Comment: Checked partition update time stamp. I could see data from old insert still available based on timestamp. Tried to drop table and reload data. This happens for only few partitions in the data.